# Unity Photon Rigidbody Addforce only works on master client

Tags: unity-game-engine, c#-3.0, game-physics, multiplayer, photon

I have 2 player and 1 ball, when the player touches the ball, the ball adding force. But its only works on master client :/

Answer (score 0):

This sort of control by multiple players is not supported by PUN (or most networking packages).
Only one player is in control and writes state updates for the others.